# pyschool is wrong ?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python and trying to do exercises at pyschools (if anyone knows what it is). Anyway, i have an exercise that asks me to do the following : Write a function percent(value, total) that takes in two numbers as arguments, and returns the percentage value as an integer.

Here's my code:

```
def percent(value, total):
    percent = value / total * 100
    return int(percent)
```

It works great in my Python Idle and it gives all the correct answers. however, when i run it in the pyschools website, it says that , for example , when the function is called with parameters 46 and 90 , the function returns 0. However, in my python idle , it correctly returns 51. 
What might be the problem ? 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You could also put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
return int(float(value) / float(total) * 100.0)
```

to ensure that both value and total are float. This way strings could be passed in and still get a proper answer.

Comment: you don't need both to be floats

Comment: -1 (a) two unnecessary float calls (b) the question calls for numbers. Silently coercing strings to float is not Pythonic.

Comment: The float calls will occur whether it is explicit or not, but to make it work with out the float will require this to be rewritten as `return int(100.0 * value / total)`.

Comment: Changing a parameter to a type that can be properly used in an operation is pythonic---it depends on your point of view.

Answer (score 6):

In python 2.x, division is integer division, in python 3.x, it's not. This probably explains your issue.

Also, you could be using brackets to make your code more readable.

Comment: You probably mean "parentheses", not "brackets". Superfluous parentheses make simple code like this LESS readable.

Comment: round brackets, open brackets, brackets (UK), or parentheses

Comment: `>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> [name(c) for c in "([{"]
['LEFT PARENTHESIS', 'LEFT SQUARE BRACKET', 'LEFT CURLY BRACKET']`

Comment: Brackets (or parentheses if you're American) would prove useful (and not superfluous) here given that `value / total * 100` is pretty ambiguous. Indeed, it might not be obvious that it is evaluated as `(value / total) * 100` and not as `value / (total * 100)`.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Only ambiguous to people who don't know that (in just about all computer languages)  multiplication and division have equal precedence and are executed left-to-right

Comment: Anyway, I have my opinion, and you have yours, there's no point in splitting hairs here.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use float division.

In your case you can apply this little trick:

```
percent = (100. * value) / total
```

when one of the factors is a float the operations give you floats. You do not need to convert all.
Note this does  not work:

```
percent = (value / total) * 100.
```

because the first operation is performed in integer  mode

(btw don't forget to convert percent to integer to fit the requirements of the school. I didnt do it for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable (`percent`) of the same name as the function is a bit dubious and makes cautious readers stop and wonder whether that's even legal. In any case you don't need a temporary variable at all. Consider using a temporary variable only to break up a long expression or when you need to do some debugging.

All you need to do to solve your problem cleanly and clearly so that it runs correctly on both Python 2.x and 3.x is to rearrange the order of evaluation and use `100.0` instead of `100` so that the first arithmetic operation is done using float arithmetic:

```
def percent(value, total):
    return int(value * 100.0 / total)
```